# Flash Builder launch failed - invalid application descriptor: Unknown namespace

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, adobe, flash-builder

I'm having difficulty getting a Flex mobile project to run on my machine. When I try and run the project I get the following error:

> Process terminated unexpectedly.
>
> invalid application descriptor: Unknown namespace:
>   http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/16.0
>
> Launch command details:  "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder
>   4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks\4.6.0\bin\adl.exe" -runtime "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64
>   Bit)\sdks\4.6.0\runtimes\air\win" -profile mobileDevice -screensize
>   320x460:320x480 -XscreenDPI 163 -XversionPlatform IOS
>   "C:\Users\dean.grobler\Adobe Flash Builder
>   4.7\ProsperityHealth\bin-debug\ProsperityHealth-app.xml" "C:\Users\dean.grobler\Adobe Flash Builder
>   4.7\ProsperityHealth\bin-debug"

I'm using Flash Builder 4.7. I've tried to read up on similar issues on the web but the few answers that I'm finding either don't work or are very vague.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is just you have indicate an unavailable AIR SDK version (16) for your current used Flex SDK (4.6.0).

So to avoid such problem you can :

- **1.** **Use the installed AIR SDK version with your Flex 4.6.0 SDK which is usually 3.x ( if you didn't have upgraded it ).**
- **2.** **Install the AIR SDK version 16 for your Flex 4.6.0 SDK.**

---

**How ?**

**1.** You can get the installed version of the AIR SDK of your Flex SDK by running the **AIR Debug Launcher (ADL)** exe which is : **"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks\4.6.0\bin\adl.exe"** using **cmd.exe** :

[image]

You can also get it more simply when creating a new project :

[image]

In my case it's : **3.1.0**, so in my `project-app.xml`, I should put :

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.1">
```

**2.** To upgrade the AIR SDK version of a Flex SDK, we do :

- **a.** Make a backup ( if you want ) of your current SDK dir, which is in your case here : **"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks\4.6.0"**. You can in any time download any Flex SDK version from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Downloads/).
- **b.** Download your desired AIR SDK ( version 16 for your case ) from Adobe [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html), the SDK not the runtime of course, and you don't need the compiler also, just the SDK.
- **c.** Unzip the downloaded file ( a zip archive ) and then copy its content and paste it into the Flex SDK dir with overwriting any existing content.
- **d.** Finally, open Flash Builder and create a new project and select your appropriate AIR SDK :

[image]

In my case, I installed many combinations of Flex and AIR SDKs.

Hope that can help.

Comment: This is actually one of the greatest answer on SO ! Thanks !