# Using an older version of AIR SDK with Flash Builder

Tags: flash, flash-builder

Is there a way to use an older version of AIR SDK with Flash Builder? The reason for this is because I need access to the following functions:

```
import avm2.intrinsics.memory.li32;
import avm2.intrinsics.memory.si32;
```

which are no longer available in the latest AIR SDK.

Comment: Take a look on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32444027/2256820) of this question, it can help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use old SDKs although it might be a much better idea to just refactor your code to let it work with the new SDKs.

**If you are using Flex / AIR:**

Use the [Apache Flex SDK tool](http://flex.apache.org/installer.html) to download your Flex / AIR SDK combination and save it somewhere on your disk. Then right-click on your project > Properties > Flex Compiler > Configure Flex SDKs. Add your your downloaded SDK to the list. Then set "Use a specific SDK" in the Flex Compiler settings to your new SDK. Make sure you have the same AIR SDK version set in your application descriptor XML file. For example, if you are using AIR 3.0 it should be something like that in the beginning of your app descriptor:

```
http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.0
```

**If you are using pure ActionScript AIR SDK:**

1. Close Flash builder
2. Go to C:/Program Files/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722 (or wherever you have your FB installed)
3. There is an AIRSDK folder. Rename it to "AIRSDK_backup". Now create a new "AIRSDK" folder and extract your desired SDK there. Make sure the structure of your AIRSDK and AIRSDK_backup is the same
4. Restart Flash Builder and you should see your new AIR SDK in the Project Properties > Actionscript compiler

Comment: My project is currently not a Flex project. I do not see the "Flex Compiler" option under properties. I see a "ActionScript Compiler" option but this does not allow me to change the compiler to anything from "AIR SDK 3.4".

Comment: Oh i see :) I've edited my response for the pure ActionScript setup