# Is Flash Builder 4.7 Still Supported by Adobe?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

I have downloaded and succesfully installed Flash Builder 4.7 from Adobe today and it all works apart from when I try to debug a project that is using the 4.6 SDK.

I get the message

```
Process terminated without establishing connection to debugger.

DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x3420c0, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x335200
invalid application descriptor: Unknown namespace: http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/21.0
```

Having looked at [this similar question from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432931/flash-builder-launch-failed-invalid-application-descriptor-unknown-namespace) it appears that my SDKs are all fine.

What is worrying me is that the error message is quoting a url that no longer exists -> http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/21.0

Does anyone know if Flash Builder 4.7 still works and is still supported by Adobe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash Builder 4.7 still works although it is not supported any more. The last update was back in 2012. In order to be able to work with it today, you have to get the latest AIR SDK for Flex and use that instead of the old 4.6 version.

You can download it [here.](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html) You can also find a guide on how to update [here.](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/kb/overlay-air-sdk-flash-builder.html)

IntelliJ or VS code are nice alternatives though.